# Mysql order column by 2 values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have the ff table

| id | type | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | private | page 1 |
| 1 | public | page 1 |
| 2 | private | page 2 |
| 3 | public | page 3 |

i want to group them by id and prioritize type "public" over "private"
so the output would be like this

| id | type | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | public | page 1 |
| 2 | private | page 2 |
| 3 | public | page 3 |

Comment: what's your mysql version?

Comment: Mysql 5.5 or Mariadb10

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use condition aggregate function to make it, writing high prioritize type in the front which you want.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id,title,MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'public' THEN 'public' ELSE 'private' END) type
FROM T
GROUP BY id,title;
```

| id | title | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | page 1 | public |
| 2 | page 2 | private |
| 3 | page 3 | public |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a2EFi8a7jxKof71t5aRLYt/1)